Finding positive integer triples satisfying $a(b - a + c) + c(ab - b^2 - b) = 0$
Find all positive integers (a,b,c) satisfying
$a(b - a + c) + c(ab - b^2 - b) = 0$
My Attempt
I am preparing for the INMO (Indian national mathematics olympiad). Currently I am focusing in number theory yesterday I found this problem
I found three solutions to this

$(2,2,1)$
$(3,2,1)$
$(4,3,1)$

To find integer triples $(a, b, c)$ that satisfy the equation
$a(b - a + c) + c(ab - b^2 - b) = 0$,
I tried by exploring values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ while looking for patterns that balance the terms of the equation.
The equation has terms that depend on combinations of $a$, $b$, and $c$. Each of these variables interacts in a way that can lead to the cancellation of terms under certain conditions, making it possible for the equation to be zero.
When expanded, the equation becomes:
$a(b - a + c) + c(ab - b^2 - b) = ab - a^2 + ac + cab - cb^2 - cb$.
Grouping similar terms, it’s evident that careful choices of $a$, $b$, and $c$ can result in zero.
By experimenting with small values of $a$, I noticed that increasing $a$ often requires $b$ and $c$ to increase in a correlated way to maintain the balance. For instance, when $a=2$, one possible solution is $(a, b, c) = (2, 2, 1)$, and as a increases, adjusting $b$ and $c$ leads to more solutions.
I began with small values for $a$, $b$, and $c$ and tested combinations. The first set of solutions came from setting $a = 2$, and trying different values of $b$ and $c$. After finding one solution, I incremented $a$ and repeated the process, often finding that increasing $a$ required a slight adjustment in $b$ or $c$.
If for a particular $a$, a combination of $b$ and $c$ didn’t work, I would try nearby values of $b$ and $c$. Many times, increasing $a$ by one unit allowed solutions with $b$ and $c$ increasing by one unit as well.
But my question is, are there anymore solutions and what is the systematic method for finding all the solutions.

One systematic approach is to factorize the polynomial. In our case we have
$$
0=a(b - a + c) + c(ab - b^2 - b) =- (a - bc - c)(a - b).
$$
In particular, all triples $(a,a,c)$ are solutions, and all triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a=bc+c$.
